# How to reference a css file in a Spring boot project whose views have a .ftlh extension?

Tags: css, spring-boot, freemarker

Project to develop an advertisement website. Wrote a standard base for an MVC project. As soon as we talk about adding frontend to the code, the browser does not see it. A link to the css file is added as a tag . The css file is located in the resources/css/login.css folder. I tried moving the file to different places, but the browser still doesn't see the css.

If anyone has ever encountered anything like this, I would appreciate your help. If you need additional information or clarification, feel free to write.